# Access Files in Azure as an end-user

Tags: azure

Next week we will replace our old server with a new one.The traditional file-share will stil be on that server and shall be synced to Azure. End users will be using the fileshare on the local server, but I want them to be able to access the same files in the Cloud, being synced with the local share. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find info on this, only info about setting up the sync, or accessing files as an admin using the Azure portal, but nothing about end-user access having the same permissions as they do on the local file-share...

Can't imagine this isn't possible...

Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about Azure File Sync?
This tool syncs your local files up to an Azure Files share, this share can be accessed by others from anywhere (if you allow it) by mapping a drive to the Azure Files share directly. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) for how this works.

However, I would caution against this approach currently for two reasons:

1. At present, if you want to map the drive to your machine you need to use the storage account key, which grants far to many rights for a normal user, and is the same key in use by everyone. There is a preview of using Azure AD DS for ACL's, but this is not production ready yet.
2. If you are using Azure File Sync, any files added or edited directly on the Azure Files share may not sync down to your file server for up to 24 hours. Changes going the other way are immediate, but there is a delay for those written directly.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for your answer! So I understand there's no end-user interface to access a synced file-share in the cloud where a user has the same rights as on the local fileshare? Are there other tools besides Azure that make this possible?